# jquery issue with slidetoggle()

Tags: jquery, css, slidetoggle

I have a div #up and and div #middle both inside a div #frame

with the css:

```
#frame{
    position: absolute;
    left:200;
    top:200;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
}

#middle{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;

}

#up{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:200;
    display:none;
}
```

When I click on #middle I'm slideToggling #up from bottom to top with the jQuery code:

```
$('#middle').click(function () {
    $('#up').slideToggle();
});
```

here a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/malamine_kebe/DCSuR/

my question :
How can I also slideToggle the border top of #frame when #up is slideToggling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DCSuR/10/)

You can not toggle element's border with inner div which has `position: absolute;`

Look at the demo, I've added border to `#up` to all sides exept bottom, and make this div override parent's (`#middle`) with `bottom: 201px;`

UPDATE 2: 
I'm not sure if you need a tab effect like  [this](http://jsfiddle.net/DCSuR/17/)

or like @Danko made [link](http://jsfiddle.net/DCSuR/21/)

Comment: +1 Your approach is great only a few more properties to fake it http://jsfiddle.net/DCSuR/21/

Comment: Oh, just wanted to made another example with full width #up, almost exactly the same you've done :)

Comment: thanks to you and to @Danko, the second link is exactly what i wanted!

Comment: @Danko but then it's gonna be complicated if i want to add some shadow no?

Comment: Yep i guess it's gonna be complicated then you may need a Jquery solution to animate ... @user2461031

Comment: Where do you want to add a shadow, to the #up?

Comment: @MiheyEgoroff I want to add a shadow to #frame then to #up when i'm toggling it

Comment: My quick advise is to change #frame's height (#frame height = #frame height + #up height ) then #up is displayed  and decrease in back then #up is hidden. Then you can add box-shadow to #frame

Comment: yes @MiheyEgoroff I thought of it too, and i'll follow your advice!! thanks a lot for your time!!

Comment: No problem, you are welcome! Try this out, if you would stuck (hope no) - come for an advise ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'ts just a CSS issue. When you use `position: absolute` the element can go outside without changing the parent frame. So if you change to `position: relative` it will works.

```
#up{
    position:relative;
    top: 0;
    display:none;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L105/DCSuR/6/)

Comment: I don't think the OP wants the middle div to be pushed down. I believe he wants it to remain in place with up sliding upward, along with the border of the container div.

Comment: thanks @L105 but yes, I din't want the middle div to be pushed down

Answer (score 1):

I guess this could be something...

```
var i = 0;
$('#middle').click(function () {
    var tp = i % 2 === 0 ? $(this).offset().top - $('#up').height() : $(this).offset().top - 2;
    $('#frame').animate({
        top: tp
    });
    $('#up').slideToggle();
    i++;
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/DCSuR/12/)